# Flutter GetX routing history

Tags: flutter, flutter-get

I it possible to see the navigator stack with GetX? I looked in the documentation but I could not find anything on this subject. I usually close for example dialogs like this

```
Get.until((route) => !Get.isDialogOpen);
```

But I was wondering if I could close routes if an instance of a specific page is in the routing history which would be something like this

```
  Get.until((route) => !Get.routingHistory.contains('/someRoute'));
```

Note this isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Do you mean you want close page from pages history when you are in another page?

Comment: I want to keep closing pages untill my navigator stack doesn't contain a instance of that route

Comment: off the route /someRoute *

Answer (score 11):

**Get.until**
Remove screens until satisfying the condition.
It’s the same with Navigation.popUntil().
You can use it like Get.until((route) => Get.currentRoute == '/home').

**Get.offNamed**
By the Named route, remove the current screen and add a new screen.
It’s the same with Navigation.pushReplacementNamed().
You can use it like Get.offNamed('/second').

**Get.offAndToNamed**
By the Named route, add a new screen and then, remove the previous screen.
It’s the same with Navigation.popAndPushNamed().
You can use it like Get.offAndToNamed('/second').

**Get.offUntil**
Remove screens until satisfying the condition, and then, add a new screen.
It’s the same with Navigation.pushAndRemoveUntil().
You can use it like Get.offUntil(page, (route) => (route as GetPageRoute).routeName == '/home').

**Get.offNamedUntil**
By the Named route, remove screens until satisfying the condition, and then, add a new screen.
It’s the same with Navigation.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil().
You can use it like Get.offNamedUntil(page, ModalRoute.withName('/home')).

Please use according to your usecase

Answer (score 6):

You need to use:

```
Get.offUntil(page, (route) => false)
```

page means the new page to navigate.

```
(route) => false
```

Is the condition.

Comment: what is the first Argument for Get.offUntil(<page>, (route) => false) or how to navigate to new page? I directly want to pass a class name at <page> and don't want to use named route as arguments. is it possible?

Comment: We can use in this way:


 RaisedButton(
                        child: Text("offUntil Fourth"),
                        onPressed: () => Get.offUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Second(),
                                maintainState: false),
                            (route) => false)),

Answer (score 4):

GetX have another useful function:

```
int times = 2;
Get.close(times);
```

Close as many routes as defined by [times]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep closing routes until you reach a page route....

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/route-name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It is possible. Navigator.popUntil pops pages until a passed predicate returns true. We can query the following route in the navigator stack and decide what decision to make. 
The GetX method for doing the same is
`

    Get.offUntil( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewPage()), (route) {
    var currentRoute = route.settings.name;
      debugPrint("Get.currentRoute --- $currentRoute");
        if(currentRoute  == "/Home") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }

`


The code above pops until home. Also, we can add custom logic in the if-else block above.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get.until((route) {
                if (route.settings.name == Routes.TEST1) {
                  //Return to the specified page
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              });
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than the existing answers. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

```
Get.offAll(Home());  // remove all previous routes and redirect to home
```

of with namedRoutes:

```
Get.offAllNamed('/home');
```

Comment: That would just rerender the Homepage, which doesn't make sense. If the homepage is already there on the stack, just use it.